# Select one record from related table if exists, else return None

Tags: django

I have this two models:

```
  class Box(models.Model):

  class BoxImages(models.Model):
     box=models.ForeignKey(Box)
     img=models.ImageField()
     cover=models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Only one image can be a cover image for a box and a box might not have any images at all. What I want now is to get list of boxes along with their cover image. But django uses inner join and brings boxes that have corresponding cover images only.

```
    Box.objects.filter(box_boximages__cover=1).values('id','box_label')
```

How do I force it to go with left join or left outer join since i read the ORM decides on its own which join to use?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have all boxes, no matter whether they have a cover image or not, just drop the `filter`. The filter effectively reduces your queryset to only those Boxes that have a cover image.

```
Box.objects.select_related('box_boximages').values('id','box_label', 'box_boximages__cover')
```

`select_related` will fetch the related BoxImages in the same query (if they exist). The queryset will contain all Box objects, even if they don't have BoxImages.

EDIT:

> It returns all images; the box appears 5 items cos there are 5 pictures for it.

Yes, you are correct. `values` will add entries per fkey relation. There are several ways to cope with that.

(a) simplest is, not to use `values` but simply iterate over the queryset and use the Box instances with their related BoxImages. The code will be easy to understand. With the `select_related` you should also be fine performance wise.

(b) use aggregation to only fetch the box images that are covers. Have a look at the `aggregate` function. You can use it in combination with `Exists` to find the cover images (or `Max`).

(c) Create two QuerySets, one with Boxes without BoxImages and the other using the BoxImage Covers to get all the related Box instances. Combine those two.

Personally, I think (a) is the simplest and therefore best to understand when reading the code at a later point or for other developers.

If you always end up selecting based on cover versus not-a-cover image *and* you have the freedom to change the models then you could think about using two models + model inheritance and create BoxCover (OneToOneRelation to Box) and BoxImage (n:1 to Box) models. This would be the easiest to understand and handle.

Comment: If a box have five images with one cover image, wouldn't that return all the 5 images without a filter of some kind? Let me try still.

Comment: Thanks Risadinha...just checked. It returns all images; the box appears 5 items cos there are 5 pictures for it.